# Data does not bind in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Controller</title>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var app = angular.module("sample", []);
                app.controller("emp", function(){
                        this.Name = "jag";
                    });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="sample">
            <div ng-controller="emp">
                Hello {{Name}}
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

---

`{{ Name }}` expression does not evaluate.

1) How to check, whether `$scope` model binds to `div` template in view?

2) I learnt that scope sits at DOM. Controller instance get created using directive `ng-controller="emp"`. Can I access controller(`emp`) instance and `$scope` through DOM?

Answer (score 2):

> Use `controller as` if you are using `this` instead of `$scope`. `Controllers` as `classes`, we are `initializing` them(`var student = new Student()`) using `controller as` syntax.

```js
var app = angular.module("sample", []);
app.controller("emp", function() {
  this.Name = "jag";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="emp as e">
    Hello {{e.Name}}
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I learnt that scope sits in DOM attached to element(`div`). Controller instance get created using directive `ng-controller="emp"`. Can I access controller(`emp`) instance and `this.Name` through DOM?

Comment: Yes! controller instance will get created but the elements will be binded to `$scope` if `controller as` is not used. You can compare the scenario with `student example`. You can deal with `this` context in the constructor and can use `properties and methods` of the class with reference of variable using which class is initialized.. Refer this if you are suppose to use `$scope`=> https://jsfiddle.net/p0jLkkbn/

Comment: How do I access controller instance using JavaScript?

Comment: Provided answer does answer this question.